# Change data in selected cell at NSTableView

Tags: swift, nstableview

I have NSTableView with cell as custom views (NSCellView). How can I get reference to this cell and change data inside on selection of that cell?

From `tableViewSelectionDidChange` I can't get reference to this cell (empty notification), `tableView willDisplayCell` not working with cell as views, `tableView.selectedCell()` returning data only for default cells (not as views).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `viewAtColumn(_:row:makeIfNecessary:)`, passing the column index of the appropriate column, the index of the selected row, and true. You'll need to cast that to your cell view class.

By the way, don't use the `NS` prefix for your own classes (`NSCellView`). Use a prefix specific to your organization or project. `NS` is reserved for Cocoa.

Code example to access specified cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
    let cell = tableView.viewAtColumn(0, row:row, makeIfNecessary:true)
}
```